# Cities within radius from current coordinates PHP API

Tags: php, geolocation, city

Well fellow programmers,

I got myself in a situation.

I am currently developing an API for a taxi application. The taxi want's to show advertisements from the current area. Now i need to specify in the Admin panel what the banner image is and the main location. Aswell as a radius in KM to show this ad aswell.

My question. Is there a simple API which i can fill in my current location and get all nearby citynames within the radius i provide aswell?

i am looking for something like this : http://www.travelmath.com/cities-within/10+km/of/Rotterdam,+Netherlands but then an API with JSON return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * @author Stefano Groenland
 * @return string
 *
 * Uses the geobyte API for nearby cities in a radius arround the lat & long coords of a given location.
 */
public function getLocationsInRadius(){
    $radius = Input::get('radius');
    $lat = Input::get('lat');
    $lng = Input::get('lng');

    $radius = $radius * 0.62137; //km to miles
    $url = 'http://gd.geobytes.com/GetNearbyCities?radius='.$radius.'&Latitude='.$lat.'&Longitude='.$lng.'&limit=999';

    $response_json = file_get_contents($url);

    $response = json_decode($response_json, true);

    return $response;
}
```

Got it working.